# How to hide overflown content of floated element

Tags: css

I have 2 columns 50% width each. Inside each column I have overflown content positioned absolutely relative to body.

```
<div class='column left'>
    <div class='inner'><h1>Pink</h1></div>
</div>
<div class='column right '>
    <div class='inner'><h1>Blue</h1></div>
</div>
```

I need the `inner` divs to be hidden. How do I do that? Setting `overflow:hidden` on .column has no effect on `inner` divs. [Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/e2rM5/12/)

PS. The idea is to animate the width of the columns and show the inner content. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2rM5/5/) illustrates what i am trying to achieve (but it is using `vh`, `vw` that I cannot use due to browser requirement)

```
html, body {
    width :100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /*has no effect*/
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100px;
}

.left .inner {
    right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

.right .inner {
    left: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: `position: absolute;` is the problem, I guess...

Comment: Probably, but I can't get on without it. I need the inner content to stick to the edge.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for

```
visibility: hidden;
```

or

```
display: none;
```

This last one removes the element from the DOM.

Comment: I can't remote the element from the dom. As I said `the idea is to animate the width of the columns and show the inner content`.